# Is there a way for a cell to keep track of max value ever recorded in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I want to track the max number ever input in one cell. The number in this cell might go up or down over time. I tried taking the max of the cell I want to track and the cell I'm using to track the max over all time but I got an error (something like F5:`=MAX(F5, F8)` where F8 is the cell I want to track).

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have a demo sheet shared with your desired result.  With that being said, if it is an onEdit event...then this will work for that one cell.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var ss = e.source;
  var tab = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = tab.getSheetName();
  var maxValue = tab.getRange(5,6).getValue();
  var value = e.value;
  var range = e.range;
  //checks if F8 is greater than F5. If so, it will replace F5 with the new value in F8
  if(sheetName == 'Sheet1' && maxValue < value && range.getRow() == 8 && range.getColumn() == 6) {
  
     tab.getRange(5,6).setValue(value);
  
  }

}
```